# MySQL query nested/sub?

Tags: mysql

OK this is the data I am working with:

```
        category_child_id category_parent_id 
                        1                  0 
                        2                  0 
                        3                  1 
                        4                  1 
                        5                  3 
                        6                  3 
                        7                  4 
                        8                  0 
                        9                  8 
                       10                  8 
                       11                  0 
                       12                 11 
                       13                 11 
                       14                  0 
                       15                 14 
                       16                 14 
                       17                 14 
                       18                  0 
                       19                 18 
                       20                 18 
                       21                 18 
                        0                 19
```

It's basically categories with sub categories etc etc.

If I

```
SELECT category_child_id FROM  category_xref WHERE category_parent_id = 1
```

it returns 3 & 4 which is correct. However there are no products in this category only in the category below so the results I actually want are 5 & 6 as well. However this is not always the same so it does need to be a query.

So basically I need to run a query to get all connected(nested) categories from the table. I've tried many ways with failed results so any help would be great.

Comment: You have a loop in your parent-child associations. This can lead to infinity loops if you query recursive through the category tree. e.g. 0 as 19 as parent, 19 has 18 as parent and 18 has 0 as parent -> loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL you could have used "WITH RECURSIVE" but MySQL does not support dynamic, recursive queries. You have to do it with your accessing language (e.g. PHP, Java).
There you can iterate over your recordset and perform a query for each returned child row until no more child rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

As TRD says, there are extensions to SQL supporting recursive searching of self-joins (Oracle uses 'CONNECT BY') however not only are these not available in MySQL, they're also not the most efficient nor flexible solution.

Have a google for adjacency list model - I did and found [this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Comment: I found something similar by googling around: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/, may be this helps Paul.